# C++, server-side logging multiply files at once

Tags: c++, logging, std, ofstream

I do have a 2D game server written in C++ that can host up to 1000 players (that limit is because of map size, not by a performance by any means).

It's optimization and so is more-or-less great, as it was written by some really good developers.

What I am now trying to do, is to attach logging for each and every player. I do want to log such actions like:
Move things within, talks, die, login and so on and so on (so basically not everything, but fairly bit of what the player is doing)

I am not having problem programming-wise, rather I do lack knowledge about how to (performance) handle it and if my attempt is any good. What I am trying to do right now is:

I, for some reason, thought that it would be good to have each player log save to different files using ofstream.open. (I do believe that's an actually bad idea, **but (1.) is it really? (2.) And why is it so? (3.) Can it handle up to 1000 files open?**) I do have a class LoggingPlayer; on player login, I create an instance of this class and follow players actions by sending information to logging function.
I do save write to file when the buffer's full. I do close file only when player logs-off. 
**If I lose file - that's not the big deal, really. If the server crashes or slows for few seconds - that's a big deal for me.**

I do have a few questions regarding:

**(4.) How can I make it better?** (e.g. using one logger for all players? log in one file?)

**(5.) Should I totally abandon trying to make my own logger** and try the already existing ones?

**(5a.)** If so, **what are the recommendations for such a case?** (online with 500-1000 users). I heard about boost log, but never tried.

I do appreciate all the help; so if you know the answer just for the one question, please don't hesitate.

Comment: Does the server has a process or a thread (or nothing) attached to each user? Is the logging part of each user realized inside a separate process or thread or just nothing?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? I believe typically game servers don't keep logs for individual players, they write them to one (or a few) specific log(s), and typically only e.g. one log file per day. When they want info on one player and during a specific time period they just parse the relevant global log files.

Comment: @KamilCuk No, nothing. This is why I think it'll struggle.
CruzJean I am unsure if that's what I want. I am seeking for ideas and your questions made me doubt. So what you're saying is that I should log to one file and that's it - then parse it for whatever I am searching for? Should I use mutex for that?